# Python API to Access Trash Folder

Tags: python, linux, api, freedesktop.org

I am looking for a good python API to access the Trash folder in Linux. This is part of a simple productivity software that will help user organize their files, and empty their trash folder on a regular basis. I want to make this work for GNOME, but I would like to expand it to other desktop environment.

Do you have any suggestion on how to get one ?

Thank you

Comment: perhaps I should rephrase it, I mean the Trash bin. I'll edit the question

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but why not just do it manually? Just programatically move things to and from the trash folder (often at $HOME/.Trash)

Comment: @jeremy I am writing a simple 'productivity' app for Linux that empties the trash folder periodically =) This is only one of the feature

Comment: Is it intended for one or another of the various desktop environments, such as [CDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Desktop_Environment), [Xfce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xfce), [GNOME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME), [KDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kde), etc?

Comment: That's fine, but there's no reason to use an API for this. Just empty out that folder occasionally.

Comment: @sarnold well I am looking for something that I can use for all sort of desktop environment. But GNOME will be a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is an API for that. I think (or rather, the voices <s>in my head</s> on the internet say) "Empty Trash" is a map to [`rm -rf ~/.Trash/*`](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/empty-ubuntu-gnome-trash-from-the-command-line.html). (Actually, that should be true for both KDE and Gnome, but I don't know about XFCE, Slim or XKCD. Of course, if you have XKCD as a windows manager, I don't think you'll ever need to worry about trash.)

Comment: @Tim It was a bit of a joke, for some reason I have a tendency to think of XKCD when I mean Xfce.